# Faster RCNN colab notebook (pycocotools) problem

Tags: object-detection, faster-rcnn, coco

I am following the faster rcnn colab notebook tutorial ([https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W7FTmqqmkj24rSzgoDQFmU41EyHD3pGf?usp=sharing](https://stackoverflow.com)), but I faced some errors (regarding building wheels in pycocotools in python 3.6) when running this command: !pip install pycocotools --no-binary pycocotools

I want to run this colab notebook on this dataset [https://universe.roboflow.com/ar-nal/sheeep-detection/dataset/1](https://stackoverflow.com)
Dataset Tensorflow TF record format: curl -L "https://universe.roboflow.com/ds/1lsVf28gQv?key=ThFeztosRX" > roboflow.zip; unzip roboflow.zip; rm roboflow.zip

Help me to run the faster rcnn colab notebook.

Comment: @Sayali_C, please have a look on the question.